# jQuery selecting attribute value of multiple elements with name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has multiple input, select, textarea elements. With jQuery, How can I get the name attribute values of each element? I have tried the following but its not working:

```
var names = $('[name]');
names.each(function(){
    console.log(names.attr('name'));
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `this` within the `each()` to refer to the element within the current iteration. Your current code is attempting to get the `name` of a set of elements which is logically incorrect. Try this:

```
var names = $('[name]');
names.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You are still using names within your [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.  Try this:

```
var names = $('[name]');
names.each(function(index, name){
    console.log($(name).attr('name'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should loop around all the required elements and output the name and value to the console.

```
$('input,select,textarea').each(function() {
  var thisname = $(this).attr('name');
  var thisval = $(this).val();
  console.log('name = ' + thisname);
  console.log('value = ' + thisval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way too.

```
var $name = $("[name]");
$name.get().map(function(elem,index){
    console.log($(elem).attr("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the elements you wish to get the names of.
Then you get all the elements from that class and iterate them to get their names.

```
formElements = $('.form-element');
for(key in formElements) {
      name = formElements[key].attr('name');
      // do what you wish with the element's name
}
```

P.S. You may need to wrap formElements[key] in $(), have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Selects elements that have the 'name' attribute, with any value.
    var htmlElements = $("[name]");

    $.each(htmlElements, function(index, htmlElement){
        // this function is called for each html element wich has attribute 'name'

        var $element = $(htmlElement);

        // Get name attribute for input, select, textarea only
        if ($element.is("input") || 
            $element.is("select") ||
            $element.is("textarea")) {
            console.log($element.attr("name"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Give your input ID then call `attr()` method

```
$("#id").attr("name");
```